# CSS Text Input---JS Fiddle Included

Tags: html, css

Here is a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1kjgkkkc/1/

HTML:

```
<form>
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
</form>
```

CSS:

```
input {
border-radius: 10px;

}

input:focus {
background: #CEECF5;

}
```

When the input box is selected a rectangular outline appears. Any thoughts on how to remove this rectangular outline all together or at least round it to the same radius as the input box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply add

```
outline:0;
```

to

```
input:focus {
background: #CEECF5;

outline:0; /* << this */
}
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/1kjgkkkc/2/)